# Android border layout with an EditText overlapping on it

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want to code a layout like the following image in xml in Android.

[image: Example]

One approach would be to have a RelativeLayout and make a 9 patch rounded rectangle border image, have it as the background around a layout which has the two blue buttons, and then have and EditText overlapping it, with its background set to a red color.

What could be other approaches?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood your question you want to make series of photos ..like Gallery application

you can do it with more option also.

1)this is gallery type application .
  so . you can use this basic code :[Android Gallery Application](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html)

2)If you want to see all the photos in circle this is also possible..
It depends upon your need ..please write in brief you want more...

Comment: Please refer to the image. I want only one layout, not photos in a circle.